# Integration by part of $\int xe^{-3x} dx$

Tags: integration

I first let $f(x)=e^{-3x} \implies f'(x)=3e^{-3x}$

$$g'(x)=x \implies g(x)=\int xdx=\dfrac{x^2}{2}$$

$$\int xe^{-3x}dx=\dfrac{x^2}{2}e^{-3x}+\int x3e^{-3x}dx$$

$$=\int xe^{-3x}dx=\dfrac{x^2}{2}e^{-3x}+3\int xe^{-3x}dx$$

$$=-2\int xe^{-3x}dx=\dfrac{x^2}{2}e^{-3x}$$

$$=\int xe^{-3x}dx=\dfrac{x^2}{4}e^{-3x}$$

This answer is wrong since the choices are $f(x)=x$ and $g'(x)=e^{-3x}$

I know that choosing functions follow this definite order: LIATE (Logarithm, Inverse, Algebra, Trigonometric, Exponential). But I didn't know that wrong choice may lead to wrong result. Could you explain to me further on this point?

Comment: There is a mistake in your integration by part. It should be $\int f(x)g'(x)dx=f(x)g(x)-\int g(x)f'(x)dx$.

Answer (score 2):

The third line should be
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int xe^{-3x}dx=\dfrac{x^2}{2}e^{-3x}+\int \color{red}{ \dfrac{x^2}{2}}  3e^{-3x}dx.
\end{eqnarray*}
But you are right ... should have differentiated the $x$ and integrated the exponential.

Answer (score 0):

We could do it this way:
$$\int xe^{-3x} dx = x\int e^{-3x} dx - \int \frac{e^{-3x}}{-3} dx$$
$$ =-x \frac{e^{-3x}}{3} -\frac{e^{-3x}}{9}+ C$$

Answer (score 0):

If $u = x$ and ${\rm d}v = {\rm e}^{-3x}\,{\rm d}x$, then ${\rm d}u = {\rm d}x$ and $v = -{\rm e}^{-3x}/3$. So $$\int u\,{\rm d}v = uv - \int v\,{\rm d}u$$becomes $$\int x{\rm e}^{-3x}\,{\rm d}x = -\frac{x{\rm e}^{-3x}}{3} - \int -\frac{{\rm e}^{-3x}}{3}\,{\rm d}x = -\frac{x{\rm e}^{-3x}}{3} + \frac{1}{3}\int {\rm e}^{-3x}\,{\rm d}x = -\frac{x{\rm e}^{-3x}}{3}  - \frac{{\rm e}^{-3x}}{9}+c.$$